# What are the most popular DNS amplification attack tools for Windows and Linux?

Tags: ddos

I would like to test my edge-router firewall rules against some DNS amplification attack traffic. I could run some DNS lookup utility in an endless loop, but maybe there are some dedicated utilities which are popular among attackers and would give a more realistic attack traffic? For example [tsunami](http://www.infosec-ninjas.com/tsunami) seems to be one such utility. If I check the `stable`, `main`, `contrib` and `non-free` repositories for *Debian 8*, then I find nothing useful:

```
# apt-cache search amplification
primer3 - Tool to design flanking oligo nucleotides for DNA amplification
sineshaper - Monophonic synth plugin with two oscillators and waveshapers
#
```

What are the most popular DNS amplification attack tools for Windows and Linux? Or are those usually custom-made utilities and scripts?

Comment: I just found Tsunami and Saddam https://github.com/OffensivePython/Saddam

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, official Debian repositories don't feature tools specifically designed to carry out amplification DDoS.

What's even more important, DNS amplification traffic itself isn't generated by any tool, that's just packets produced by innocent DNS servers. A tool is needed though to trick those DNS servers into sending huge replies towards victim's IP address. Using innocent DNS servers, run by others, to generate a DDoS attack, even towards your own network infrastructure, could be strictly unlawful in your country.

My advice is to study how DNS replies are structured and to use [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) or any other packet generator to replicate them towards your firewall.